# Rails with Devise and user_id in cookie

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I build Rails app and now try to install CometChat for it. On installation instruction is function like this:

```
function getUserID() {
    $userid = 0; // Return 0 if user is not logged in

    if (!empty($_COOKIE['userid'])) {
        $userid = $_COOKIE['userid'];
    }

    return $userid;
}
```

As i understand i need userid in cookie, right? How can i change this code to work with rails sessions.

I set (i think) cookie like this in Session_controller - finded on stackoverflow:

```
def create
  cookies[:sign_in] = current_user.id
  super
end

  # GET /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    cookies[:sign_out] = current_user.id
    super
  end
```

But im do not know how to integrate with this function getUserID. Can somebody help with that - i do not know php and dont want to destroy something :)

Comment: "CometChat: PHP chat software", how can you add PHP stuff to Rails app?

Comment: because it works? -- No modifications are required to your existing Ruby on Rails site code.The only modification that needs to be performed in your existing code is to add a cookie like userid

Comment: ok cometchat installed but still something is wrong with cookie

Comment: OK and cookie works to - cookies[:userid] - cometchat works with rails :)